ngx-intl-tel-input dropdown hover effect how to disable
Problem:
I am seeing a gray background color when I hover over the dropdown items in the country list. I want to disable this hover color while keeping the dropdown functional. I tried using background-color: transparent !important;, but the gray color still appears.
What I've Tried:
Setting background-color: transparent !important; on .iti__country-list .iti__country:hover
Using different background colors and even initial, but none of these worked.
<div class="form-field">
  <label for="phone">Phone Number<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <ngx-intl-tel-input
    class="ngx-tel-input"
    [preferredCountries]="['us', 'gb']"
    [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true"
    [enablePlaceholder]="true"
    [searchCountryFlag]="true"
    [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Name, SearchCountryField.DialCode]"
    [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.UnitedStates"
    [separateDialCode]="true"
    formControlName="mobileNumber"
  ></ngx-intl-tel-input>
</div>




.ngx-tel-input .iti {
    width: 99% !important;
  }
   
  .ngx-tel-input input {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding-left: 60px !important; /* Adjust padding-left for alignment with other fields */
    height: 74px; /* Matching the height of other form fields */
    border-radius: 61px; /* Same border-radius as other inputs */
    background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.23);
    border: 1px solid #CDC9C9; /* Consistent border */
  }
   
  .ngx-tel-input .iti__flag-container {
    width: 60px !important; /* Flag container width */
    height: 74px !important; /* Match the height of the input */
  }
   
  .ngx-tel-input input::placeholder {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.507) !important; /* Placeholder color matching */
  }
   
  .ngx-tel-input input:focus {
    border-color: var(--dark) !important; /* Focus border color for consistency */
    box-shadow: none !important; /* Remove shadow on focus */
  }
  /* Adjust placeholder alignment for the phone number input */
  .ngx-tel-input input::placeholder {
    padding-left: 30px; /* Add some padding to the left to move the placeholder */
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.507); /* Maintain the existing placeholder color */
  }
  /* Remove rounded corners of the search input */
  .iti__country-list .iti__search input {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border: none !important; /* To remove any borders */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; /* Optional: add a bottom border if needed */
  }
   
   
 
  .ngx-tel-input input {
    padding-left: 83px  !important; /* Adjust left padding to make space for the flag and dial code */
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 74px;
    border-radius: 61px;
    background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.23);
    border: 1px solid #CDC9C9;
  }
  .ngx-tel-input .iti__country .iti__name {
    margin-left: 15px; /* Adjust the margin as needed for spacing */
    font-size: 16px;   /* You can also adjust the font size if necessary */
  }

  .ngx-tel-input .iti__flag-container {
    width: 90px!important;
    height: 54px!important;
    padding-left: 14px;
}

.step_1_form {
    padding: 50px;
}

.ngx-tel-input .iti__country-list .iti__selected-dial-code:hover {
    background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 0.5); 
}

Problem:
I am seeing a gray background color when I hover over the dropdown items in the country list. I want to disable this hover color while keeping the dropdown functional. I tried using background-color: transparent !important;, but the gray color still appears.
What I've Tried:
Setting background-color: transparent !important; on .iti__country-list .iti__country:hover
Using different background colors and even initial, but none of these worked.

please share a stackblitz where the issue happens, I can't see any gray color in their official examples stackblitz demo

i Modified  the post now you can check

You can use the below CSS, which sets the background-color to transparent, which might fix your issue.
.iti--allow-dropdown .iti__flag-container:hover .iti__selected-flag {
  background-color: transparent;
}

Just inspect element the problem element, then on the right sidebar click :hov to simulate hover, then check the elements, one of the CSS will have background-color. copy this CSS and paste in your CSS to modify it.
Stackblitz Demo
